# Can't parse api using retrofit2

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit2

I'm trying to parse https://favqs.com/api/ using retorfit2 First, I want to at least extract the date from json

```
@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Example {

    @SerializedName("qotd_date")
    @Expose
    private String qotdDate;
    @SerializedName("quote")
    @Expose
    private Quote quote;

    public String getQotdDate() {
        return qotdDate;
    }

    public void setQotdDate(String qotdDate) {
        this.qotdDate = qotdDate;
    }

    public Quote getQuote() {
        return quote;
    }

    public void setQuote(Quote quote) {
        this.quote = quote;
    }

}
```

class Quote:

```
@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Quote {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("dialogue")
    @Expose
    private Boolean dialogue;
    @SerializedName("private")
    @Expose
    private Boolean _private;
    @SerializedName("tags")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> tags = null;
    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    private String url;
    @SerializedName("favorites_count")
    @Expose
    private Integer favoritesCount;
    @SerializedName("upvotes_count")
    @Expose
    private Integer upvotesCount;
    @SerializedName("downvotes_count")
    @Expose
    private Integer downvotesCount;
    @SerializedName("author")
    @Expose
    private String author;
    @SerializedName("author_permalink")
    @Expose
    private String authorPermalink;
    @SerializedName("body")
    @Expose
    private String body;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Boolean getDialogue() {
        return dialogue;
    }

    public void setDialogue(Boolean dialogue) {
        this.dialogue = dialogue;
    }

    public Boolean getPrivate() {
        return _private;
    }

    public void setPrivate(Boolean _private) {
        this._private = _private;
    }

    public List<Object> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(List<Object> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Integer getFavoritesCount() {
        return favoritesCount;
    }

    public void setFavoritesCount(Integer favoritesCount) {
        this.favoritesCount = favoritesCount;
    }

    public Integer getUpvotesCount() {
        return upvotesCount;
    }

    public void setUpvotesCount(Integer upvotesCount) {
        this.upvotesCount = upvotesCount;
    }

    public Integer getDownvotesCount() {
        return downvotesCount;
    }

    public void setDownvotesCount(Integer downvotesCount) {
        this.downvotesCount = downvotesCount;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getAuthorPermalink() {
        return authorPermalink;
    }

    public void setAuthorPermalink(String authorPermalink) {
        this.authorPermalink = authorPermalink;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

}
```

class Client:

```
public interface Client {

    @GET("qotd_date")
    Call<List<Example>> reposForUser();
}
```

class MyAdapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Example> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Example> values;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Example> values) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item_pagination, values);

        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater =
                    (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_pagination, parent, false);
        }

        TextView textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_item_pagination_text);

        Example item = values.get(position);
        String message = item.getQotdDate();
        textView.setText(message);

        return row;
    }
}
```

class MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.pagination_list);


        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://favqs.com/api/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

        Client client = retrofit.create(Client.class);
        Call<List<Example>> call = client.reposForUser();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Example>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Example>> call, Response<List<Example>> response) {
                List<Example> repos = response.body();

                listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, repos));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Example>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The application starts up but does not output anything in listView. Toast displays the message: "error :("

Мaybe the problem occurs in this part of the code:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Example>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Example>> call, Response<List<Example>> response) {
        List<Example> repos = response.body();
        Log.d("mylog1", String.valueOf(repos));
        Log.d("mylog1","mylog");

        listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, repos));
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<Example>> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

code after `call.enqueue (new Callback <List <Example>> () {` does not start executing

method starts `onFailure(Call<List<Example>> call, Throwable t)`

string `t.printStackTrace();` gives an error message:

```
W/System.err: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1562)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1403)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:592)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:424)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:74)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:40)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:243)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:153)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:174)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
    A resource failed to call close.
```

Comment: I think your service is not correct "qotd_date", try the next "qotd"

Comment: @Manuel Mato, unfortunately, an error still appears

Comment: Remove the List from your call, because the endpoint https://favqs.com/api/qotd return an object, not a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the List from your call, because the endpoint favqs.com/api/qotd return an object, not a list